# how to initialize iteration of for loop in continue statement using smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I have this bunch of code, here I am fetching all year data, so in `foreach` I am checking one condition; if year is greater than equal to current year then skipping that year using continue statement.

My problem is while skipping years, iteration also skipping as per skipped years.

If 2 years skipped, then iteration will start from 3 instead of 1.

Is there any solution how can i redefine iteration variable in smarty .

Using smarty template I am not getting any solutions how to initialize iteration variable in else part.

Below i have posted my code:

```html
 {foreach from=$histories key=year  item=i name=foo }
    {if $i.year >= date("Y")}
    {continue}
    {else}
   //how to initialise smarty variable here to 1;  
    {/if}
    <tr>
    <td><a href="{$urls.history_details|replace:'%s':$i.year}">{$smarty.foreach.foo.iteration}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{$urls.history_details|replace:'%s':$i.year}">{$i.year}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{$urls.history_details|replace:'%s':$i.year}">{$i.country}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{$urls.history_details|replace:'%s':$i.year}">{$i.location}    </a></td>

    </tr>

    {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than skipping iteration if condition met; you can proceed with your data in reverse manner, you can proceed with data ***if year is less than current year***

Here is what you can do is;

```
{foreach from=$histories key=year  item=i name=foo }
    {if $i.year < date("Y")}
        {* Your code with row details here *}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```